# pass text to an onclick function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass text element (a string) to an on click function:

```
document.getElementById("struct_list").innerHTML="<li onClick='ClickStructList("+text+");'><a href='#'>"+text;`
```

ClickStructList is defined as follow:

```
ClickStructList=function(text){
window.alert("click");
window.alert(text);
};
```

This doesn't work, firefox debug istelling me: "C is not defined", C is the value of text.

Thanks for any help

PS: I do not want to use jquery

Comment: What doesn't work? The javascript code itself or when you click on the element?

Comment: when I click nothing happen, if I remove the text argument it works, I get the "click" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotation marks were missing in your call to ClickStructList ...
this works :

```
 var ClickStructList=function (text) {
  window.alert("click");
  window.alert(text);
 };

 var text="Hello World";
 document.getElementById("struct_list").innerHTML="<li    
   onClick='ClickStructList(\""+text+"\");'><a href='#'>"+text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to define your function as a function not variable

```
function ClickStructList(text){
   window.alert("click");
   window.alert(text);
};
```

Also when you define your `onClick` callback you should surround it by quotation

```
<li onClick='ClickStructList("My entered text");'>
```

so in your example:

```
.innerHTML="<li onClick='ClickStructList(\""+text+"\");'>
```

Comment: I tried now I have this error:ReferenceError: ClickStructList is not defined

Answer (score 2):

try by changing your JS code to this:

```
document.getElementById("struct_list").innerHTML="<li onClick='ClickStructList(\""+text+"\");'><a href='#'>"+text;
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the quote-signs for the string, so JS tries to parse your text as Code.

You need at least sth like this:

```
 ... "<li onClick='ClickStructList(\""+text+"\");'><a href='#'>" ...
```

or even better

```
 ... "<li onClick='ClickStructList("+ JSON.stringify(text) +");'><a href='#'>" ...
```

Comment: that last one is the best posted so far: 100% foolproof